# Reading from a file, running out of memory

Tags: java, file, csv, io

I was just recently asked an interview question that held to deal with reading from a CSV file and summing up entries in certain cells. When asked to optimize it, I couldn't answer how to deal with the case of running out of memory if we were given a CSV of size say 100 gigs.

In Java, how exactly does reading from a file work? How do we know when something is too big? How do we deal with that? I was told that you could pass in the intermediate reader object instead of trying to read the entire thing?

Comment: Process one row at a time.

Comment: You do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/309718/940217), except instead of appending to a StringBuilder, do the summation calculation on the spot. Trying to store the whole input file in memory is what would cause trouble.

Answer (score 2):

The interviewer gave you a hint - `BufferedReader`. It is an efficient choice for reading a large file line by line.

Small example:

```
String line;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader("c:/test.txt");
while ((line= br.readLine()) != null) {
   //do processing
} 
br.close();
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) is the documentation

Comment: You don't need to initialize `line` here.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to read from a file in Java, some of them involve keeping all of the files lines (or data) in memory as you "read" the data delimited by something like a newline character (reading line by line for example).

For large files you want to process smaller bits at a time using the `Scanner`class (or something like it to read specific bytes at a time).

Sample code:

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
Scanner sc = new Scanner(inputStream, "UTF-8");
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
   String line = sc.nextLine();
   // System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `RandomAccessFile` to read the file. It may not be the best solution though.